# Swift 2.0 makes error when i try to call in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

When I try to make phone call with my app, Xcode give this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I'm really frustrated and I can't understand why it's doing this. Please take a look at my code and tell me what is wrong.

```
@IBOutlet var phonenumber: UITextField!

@IBAction func call(sender: UIButton!) {

    let  phoneN1umber = phonenumber.text
    let url = NSURL(string: "tel//:\(phoneN1umber)")!
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    webView.loadRequest(request)


}

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Comment: It is better to have safe unwrapping of the url, as  it is optional.  use an if..let check to ensure url is non nil.

Comment: @nshebbar What do you mean? Put if beside let?

Comment: yes, please see I posted the answer.

Comment: Yes, put if before let. Read about optionals in Swift. Here is a pretty good article: http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/swift-optionals-use-let/

Comment: Please think about actually thinking about a problem before resorting to stack overflow, this kind of stuff is covered in the (free) book from Apple and many many many other stack overflow questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would safely unwrap the NSURL :

```
@IBAction func call(sender: UIButton!) {

    let  phoneN1umber = phonenumber.text
    if let url = NSURL(string: "tel//:\(phoneN1umber)")
    {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webView.loadRequest(request)

    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, the call button is not doing anything.